# Lua - How to use a local variable (image URL) in a function to print an image (loadRemoteImage)?

Tags: json, variables, lua

I have a code in Lua. In the first function, I get a JSON data and put it in a variable (item1), and am able to print it. In the second function, I would like to use this variable to show the image (because item1 is an image URL). I tried a forward declaration like this and put it in the second function, but it does not work. How can this be solved?

```
local item1

local function networkListener( event )
    local res = json.prettify( event.response )
    local decoded = json.decode( res )
    if ( event.isError ) then
        print( "--Network error-- ", ( res ) )
    else
        print( "Results: " .. ( res ) )
        item1 = decoded.results.bindings[0].image.value
        print(item1)
        local myText = display.newText(sceneGroup, item1, 10, 100, native.systemFont, 26 )
        myText:setFillColor( 1, 1, 1 )
    end
end

params.body = body
network.request("http://example.com/data.json", "GET", networkListener, params)

local function networkListener2( event )
    if ( event.isError ) then
        print ( "Network error - download failed" )
    else
        event.target.alpha = 0
        transition.to( event.target, { alpha = 1.0 } )
    end

    print ( "event.response.fullPath: ", event.response.fullPath )
    print ( "event.response.filename: ", event.response.filename )
    print ( "event.response.baseDirectory: ", event.response.baseDirectory )
end

display.loadRemoteImage(item1, "GET", networkListener2, "item1.png", system.TemporaryDirectory, 50, 50 )
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the `display.loadRemoteImage()` is called before previous `network.request()` has finished its job. Callback `networkListener` wasn't triggered yet, so `item1` variable is not assigned.

You should schedule `loadRemoteImage()` from within within `networkListener`, or anywhere else where you will know that the url was successfully read, i.e. previous request has finished.

Comment: OK, @Vlad, thanks for a quick reply. For example, what would you suggest? What would be the simplest solution?

Comment: @user7665853, just move the call to `display.loadRemoteImages()` into `networkListener` callback, in the `if` branch for successful json download. Note that you should have `networkListener2` visible before defining `networkListener`.

Answer (score 0):

```
local function networkListener2( event )
        if ( event.isError ) then
            print ( "Network error - download failed" )
        else
            event.target.alpha = 0
            transition.to( event.target, { alpha = 1.0 } )
        end

        print ( "event.response.fullPath: ", event.response.fullPath )
        print ( "event.response.filename: ", event.response.filename )
        print ( "event.response.baseDirectory: ", event.response.baseDirectory )
    end

local function networkListener( event )
    local res = json.prettify( event.response )
    local decoded = json.decode( res )
    if ( event.isError ) then
        print( "--Network error-- ", ( res ) )
    else
        print( "Results: " .. ( res ) )
        item1 = decoded.results.bindings[0].image.value
        print(item1)
        local myText = display.newText(sceneGroup, item1, 10, 100, native.systemFont, 26 )
        myText:setFillColor( 1, 1, 1 )      

        display.loadRemoteImage(item1, "GET", networkListener2, "item1.png", system.TemporaryDirectory, 50, 50 )

        -- Position should be set by the center of the text object
        local myText = display.newText(sceneGroup, item1, 10, 300, native.systemFont, 26 )
        myText:setFillColor( 1, 1, 1 )
        local myText2 = display.newText(sceneGroup, item2, 10, 500, native.systemFont, 26 )
        myText:setFillColor( 1, 1, 1 )
    end
end

params.body = body
network.request("http://example.com/data.json", "GET", networkListener, params)
```